# Display matrix between each instance of a different group matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have one main report that contains a tablix that is grouped and show the result fine and page breaking within each group of the matrix.

What I'm trying to achieve is to show a different matrix (with different DataSet) next to each group of the previous matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question is lacking in the details we would need to help you with your problem.  Could you provide some screenshots of what is currently happening and perhaps a mock-up of what you need to see?  Also, take a look at [mre] for more details on how to ask a good question to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a subreport inside my matrix and that did the trick.